# Spark:How to use join method?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Now I have 2 RDDs to join but when I typed ".join" my IDE couldn't find this symbol, it told me "Cannot resolve symbol join".I have already used maven to build my project and reimport function to deal with my dependency.
Is there some dependency I missed?
Could someone tell me how to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: please add the code snippet (containing RDD definitions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enable to enable Spark implicit convertions by importing `org.apache.spark.SparkContext._` to access extra functions available on RDDs of (key, value) pairs.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

val p1: RDD[(K, V)] = ...
val p2: RDD[(K, W)] = ...
val joined: RDD[(K, (V, W))] = p1.join(p2)
```

Comment: I'm sure I have already imported this lib, but it still "Cannot resolve symbol join"

Comment: Then your RDDs are probably not of type ``(key, value)``

Comment: Please check key types also